# Loading multiple svndumps into one repository

Tags: svn

I have several dumps of different folders in a repository. They were created like this:

```
svnrdump dump https://repo-address/trunk/folder1 >dump1
svnrdump dump https://repo-address/trunk/foo/folder2 >dump2
svnrdump dump https://repo-address/trunk/foo/folder3 >dump3
```

Now, I want to load all three dumps into a single repository. I already loaded one of them, and it seems to work fine. But loading any of the other two gives me trouble.

First of all, when loading dump2, I get an error that trunk already exists. That's certainly true, since it was already part of dump1.

Even if I circumvent that error somehow, I anticipate there will be more problems.

Is there a way to load the dumps one after another? Do they need merging? If so, how?

I do not have access to the original repository anymore.

Comment: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.incremental

Comment: What is the links supposed to tell me? I have made the dumps already. I did not use the incremental switch. Can I convert a non-incremental dump into an incremental one? Wouldn't the incremental dumps result in the same problems? Why would svnadmin load an incremental dump that adds trunk even if trunk already exists but not a non-incremental dump?